# Sucesión de Fibonacci con arrays en C

Tags: array, c, fibonacci

Tengo un problema con este programa. Se supone que debe crear un .txt de un número N de la sucesión de Fibonacci almacenado en un array de tal forma que las unidades se almacenen en a[0], las decenas en a[1]... Cuando en una espacio del array se sume un numero mayor que 9 se debe sumar uno en la casilla de al lado. Pero no funciona, crea un monton de numeros negativos.¡ Ayuda por favor!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {
int numero;

printf("Introduce un valor de n: ");
scanf("%d",&numero);

double naureo = (1+sqrt(5))/2;
int dim = (int)(log10(144)+(numero-1)*log10(naureo));

int inicial [dim];
int inicial2 [dim];
int final [dim];
int primero[dim];

inicial [0]= 0;
inicial2 [0]=1;
final [0] = 0;

int contador = 0;

while (contador != numero){
int llevada = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i<dim ; i++){
    int suma = inicial[i] + inicial2[i] + llevada;
    if (suma > 9){
        final [i] = final[i] + suma%10;
        llevada = 1;
    }else{
        final [i]=suma;
    }
}
for (int i = 0 ; i<dim ; i++){
primero[i] = inicial[i];
inicial[i] = inicial2[i];
inicial2[i] = final[i];
}
contador ++;
}
int nom = dim-1;

FILE * out;
for (nom; nom >=0 ;nom--){
    fprintf(out,"%d",final[nom]);
}



 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código tiene varios errores, te recomiendo que los corrijas 1 a 1 e intentes ver que falla. Prueba primero a quitar la parte de escribir en un archivo y usa simplemente algun printf para mostrar los resultados:

Aparecen números negativos porque no has inicializado nada ahí, asi que imprime cosas más o menos aleatorias. En lugar de

```
inicial [0]= 0;
inicial2 [0]=1;
final [0] = 0;
```

deberias poner

```
for (i=0;i<dim;i++){
    inicial [i]= 0;
    inicial2 [i]=0;
    final [i] = 0;
}
inicial2 [0]=1;
```

Así todos los valores iniciales son 0.

Después en la suma tienes 2 errores. La `llevada` nunca se vuelve 0 y si el resultado de `suma` es mayor que 9, hay que guardar solo `suma%10`, no `final[i]+suma%10`. Esta sería la suma corregida:

```
for (i = 0 ; i<dim ; i++){
int suma = inicial[i] + inicial2[i] + llevada;
llevada=0;
if (suma > 9){
    final [i] = suma%10;
    llevada = 1;
}else{
    final [i]=suma;
}
}
```

Por último, para escribir en un documento no es suficiente con crear un puntero. Tienes que abrir el documento, en este caso en modo escritura. En lugar de `FILE * out;`, pon `FILE * out = fopen("out.txt", "w");`. El primer parámetro es el nombre del documento, el segundo el modo, "w" significa "write", escribir en ingles.

Acuerdate de cerrar el archivo antes de terminar el programa poniendo `fclose(out)`.

PD: Tienes 3 faltas de ortografía solo en el título "SucesiÓn de fIbonacci en arrays eN c". Si quieres que la gente le dedique tiempo a responderte ponle algo de tiempo a hacer bien la pregunta, por favor.

Comment: Muchas gracias y discúlpame por las faltas de ortografía.